# How do I use epo_ops module in VS code?

Tags: python, import, modulenotfounderror

I'm unable to use epo_ops module in vscode and pip install epo_ops is not working. is there any other method to use this module in vscode?

In code window I was writing:
input
import epo_ops
In terminal I was trying to install the epo_ops module by writing:
pip install epo_ops

I wanted to use this module but the error shown by the vs code is ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'epo_ops'
how to solve this error?